# How to remove the GetAll/Get/Create/Delete/Update from the auto generated controllers routes based on an AsyncCrudAppService in aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

By creating an application service which is based on an AsyncCrudAppService, you will get the auto generated api controllers for it, however, the routes are not really like a Rest API. If the entity name is "Project", the routes will be

- /api/services/app/Projects/GetAll [GET]
- /api/services/app/Projects/Get [GET]
- /api/services/app/Projects/Create [POST]
- /api/services/app/Projects/Update [PATCH]
- /api/services/app/Projects/Delete [Delete]

But I would like to see somthing like:

- /api/services/app/Projects [GET]
- /api/services/app/Projects/{id} [GET]
- /api/services/app/Projects [POST]
- /api/services/app/Projects/{id} [PATCH]
- /api/services/app/Projects/{id} [Delete]

I know that I could do something like this, but of course I don't like it:

```
[Route("api/services/app/projects")]
        [HttpPost]
        public override Task<ProjectDto> CreateAsync(CreateProjectDto input){
            return base.CreateAsync(input);
        }
```

Is there a better solution for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use `[Obsolete]` attribute top of function, and then removed from swagger.

Comment: What I meant is how to use http methods instead of having the the functionality in the route names! To list all projects, route should be " /api/projects" without a "GetAll"